# Rearrange array element based on the number sequence and represent by array id

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

Suppose, I have multiple arrays in one array with the number from 0 to n in multiple order.
For example,

```
x = [[0,2,3,5],[1,4]]
```

Here we have two arrays in x. There could be more than two.

I want to get rearrange all the array elements based on their number sequence. However, they will represent their array ID. The result should be like this

```
y = [0,1,0,0,1,0]
```

That means 0,2,3,5 is in array id 0. So, they will show the id in their respective sequence. Same for 1 and 4. Can anyone help me to solve this? [N.B. There could be more than two arrays. So, it will be highly appreciated if the code work for different array numbers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can do this by using a `dictionary`

```
x = [[0,2,3,5],[1,4]]
lst = {}
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
        lst[x[i][j]] = i
print(lst)
```

2. You can also do this by using `list`, `list.insert(idx, value)` means `value` is inserted to the list at the `idx`th index. Here, we are traversing through all the values of `x` and the value `x[i][j]` is in the `i` th number array.

```
x = [[0,2,3,5],[1,4]]
lst = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
        lst.insert(x[i][j], i)
print(lst)
```

Output: `[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]`

Comment: @Lzz0 i hope you got it

Comment: Using insert on a list is an `O(n)` operation since all the values that come after the insert index need to be moved down in memory every time, so it would be bad for big lists. Therefore I think you should put your dictionary solution as the first one since it will be more efficient for the OP.

Comment: @ShashSinha thanks for your comment, updated.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider using `np.argsort` for rearranging your array values and create the index-array with list comprehension:

```
x = [[0,2,3,5],[1,4]]
order = np.concatenate(x).argsort()
np.concatenate([ [i]*len(e) for i,e in enumerate(x) ])[order]
```

> array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])